# github_api gives empty results when search by location and repos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github-api

I am using `github_api` gem in my rails application, when i am sending a request to location or repos individual it gives perfect output but when i am send combination of both (location and repos) api gives empty results. I drop my logic below,

LOGIC:

```
github = Github.new github.search.users keyword:"location:bangalore repos:1", type:'user',ref:'searchresults'
```

Generated request url is

https://api.github.com/legacy/user/search/location%3Abangalore+repos%3A1?type=user&ref=searchresults

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I get the results with this URL: https://api.github.com/legacy/user/search/location:bangalore%20repos:1

I suspect github_api isn't anticipating these kinds of keywords and is not properly encoding that fragment of the URL. I would advise you to try [`octokit`](https://github.com/pengwynn/octokit) which is the official GitHub API wrapper written in Ruby. I doubt that will have this issue.

For what it's worth, if you need a python wrapper my [`github3.py`](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py) works fine in this situation as well. (That's where I got the generated URL from above)

Answer (score 0):

I debug library, in url.rb file applying CGI::escape for keyword so it generating request url is like

https://api.github.com/legacy/user/search/location%3Abangalore+repos%3A1?type=user&ref=searchresults

but this URL gives empty results because the " + " symbol is not encoding. So i am override that code now it generates request URL as

https://api.github.com/legacy/user/search/location%3Abangalore%20repos%3A1?type=user&ref=searchresults

Override code is,

```
require "github_api"
include ERB::Util


module Github
  module Utils
    module Url
      def escape(s)
        u s.to_s
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You should submit this upstream